# Unable to get JSON report for failed scenario using protractor

Tags: json, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm working on cucumber protractor framework, And by giving the below comment I cab able to get the report in JSON format for successfully executed scenarios. But if my scenarios got failed I'm unable to get the JSON report.

In **conf.js** I have added the line: **resultJsonOutputFile: 'report1.json',**

And after executing I can able to see the below comments in comment prompt:

> [15:54:39] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected true to be false
>
> [15:54:39] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

But unable to get the JSON report. Could any one help me to get the JSON report for all success & failure execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you add [this](https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework#uncaught-exceptions) `ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true` to your protractor-config file it should not throw the 199 error code.

If you've configured the `format: 'json: result.json'` like described [here](https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework#formatters-when-tests-are-sharded-or-with-multi-capabilities) it should now output the result to a file.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment, But after added the comment **"ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,"** 199 error code not displaying but getting new error as **E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining**. Also If I added **format: 'json:results.json'** I'm getting results.json without executing the scenarios (All steps are displayed as pass).

Comment: But is the report generated? and can you place some more log here?

Comment: JSON file created with all step pass without any execution. I added format: 'json:results11.json', & ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true, in cucumberOpts.

Comment: Nope... Actually the scenarios are not executing. Without executing it shown as pass after I added the above comments.

Comment: Can you place your complete setup here, it's now not clear how the setup is and what it causing your problems

Comment: Please find my config: ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: '../setup/hooks.js',
    tags: '@test',
 strict: true,
 format: 'json:results11.json',
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
  }

Comment: Hi @wswebcreation, I have posted my conf file in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299595/json-report-not-generating-for-failed-scenarios-using-protractor