# JSON report not generating for failed scenarios using protractor

Tags: json, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

If my scenarios got failed the JSON report not generating. But for passes scenarios I can able to see the JSON report.

Please find my config file as below.

[image]

In comment prompt console I can able to see the failure message:

> W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error AssertionError: expected false to equal true
>
> E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining

Comment: Which version of CucumberJS are you using?

Comment: I'm using the cucumberjs v1.3.1 & Protractor v5.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the report by using a hook, so don't generate the file form the `protractor.conf.js` file, but use a cucumber-hook for it.

The hook can look like this

**reportHook.js:**

```js
const cucumber = require('cucumber');
const jsonFormatter = cucumber.Listener.JsonFormatter();
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const jsonFile = require('jsonfile');
const path = require('path');
const projectRoot = process.cwd();

module.exports = function reportHook() {
  this.registerListener(jsonFormatter);

  /**
   * Generate and save the report json files
   */
  jsonFormatter.log = function(report) {
    const jsonReport = JSON.parse(report);

    // Generate a featurename without spaces, we're gonna use it later
    const featureName = jsonReport[0].name.replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase();

    // Here I defined a base path to which the jsons are written to
    const snapshotPath = path.join(projectRoot, '.tmp/json-output');

    // Think about a name for the json file. I now added a featurename (each feature
    // will output a file) and a timestamp (if you use multiple browsers each browser 
    // execute each feature file and generate a report)
    const filePath = path.join(snapshotPath, `report.${featureName}.${new Date}.json`);

    // Create the path if it doesn't exists
    fs.ensureDirSync(snapshotPath);

    // Save the json file
    jsonFile.writeFileSync(filePath, jsonReport, {
      spaces: 2
    });
  };
}
```

You can save this code to the file `reportHook.js` and then add it to the `cucumberOpts:.require` so it will look like this in your code

```js
cucumberOpts: {
  require: [
    '../step_definitions/*.json',
    '../setup/hooks.js',
    '../setup/reportHook.js'
  ],
  ....
}
```

Even with failed steps / scenario's it should generate the report file.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. But I'm getting **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\....\Desktop\demo\.tmp\json-output\report.....json'** error message after added the **'../setup/reportHook.js'** file. Note: The error message occurs before executing the scenarios.

Comment: Hi @KAK,Sorrym, I made an error in the code, the hook should now be correct. I had a return statement in it that instantly executed the code

Comment: Hi Still I'm getting the error message **Error: ENOENT** if I replace the filePath with exist json then its working fine. But it only working for passed scenarios and for failed I think there is some issue on my basic configuration and I raised the query as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310020/all-steps-shown-as-pass-before-protractor-cucumber-execution

Comment: It's really strange, I've did a lot of CucumberJS implementations with CucumberJs 1.x and currently also with versoon 2.x and I don't have any problems.