# Failed to save cucumber test results to Json file in server

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor, bdd, allure

When I try to execute the Protractor Cucumber framework in Jenkins under the server it successfully generates the report with the below error. When I execute the same code in Jenkins under the local machine the report is generated successfully without any error.

**Allure Report:**
[image]

**Console Error:**
[image]

Comment: Try save to save the json output result in [Cucumber hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44300546/4197679)

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber reporter fails if you are trying to save e.g.

```
reports/cucumber/cucumber_reports.json
```

and if the folder cucumber does not exist in the reports folder then it crashes.

Try sharing your protractor.conf.js file